# Subprocess y obtención de IP en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-2.x

Estoy intentando mostrar mi IP privada y pública en un pequeño programa en Python. Deseo que este se guarde en una variable y poder llamar luego a la variable algo como

```
print("su direccion ip es", VARIABLE)
```

He estado trabajando con el modulo `os.system` pero es poco eficiente, por lo que estoy intentando hacer esto con subprocess para ello.

Código:

```py
Import os
import subprocess

ipv4 = subprocess.call(["hostname","-I"])
```

Esto muestra enseguida en la consola la IP. Por lo que no me deja agregar un print.

Answer (score 1):

Puede depender de tu configuraicón de red y el camino que decidas, para esto primero debes conocer como se obtiene la dirección IP en tu router, y como se asigna por tu proveedor de servicios.
Entendiendo este punto, verás que se pueden realizar configuraciones de IP sobre tu router e incluso configurar tu propio router privado, y por tanto, obtener tu IP pública de distintas formas, incluido sin necesidad de realizar peticiones externas.

Si tienes una intranet o capa de red intermedia, podría ser que esa IPV4 de tu máquina no sea tu IP pública real, por lo que deberías "consultar al router" o externamente, sino a otro servicio intermedio.

Machine localhost

```
import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname()
local_ip_socket = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
print(local_ip_socket)
```

Machine IPV4 a través de petición usando socket. La ip 8.8.8.8 es el servicio oficial DNS de google (comúnmente usado para comprobar rápidamente si tienes conexión a internet en la terminal haciendo `ping 8.8.8.8`)

```
import socket
skt = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
skt.connect(("8.8.8.8"), 80)
print(skt.getsockname()[0])
```

IP pública (petición externa usando requests)

```
from requests import get
public_ip_get = get("http://api.ipify.org").text
print(public_ip_get)
```

IP pública (petición externa usando urllib)

```
import urllib.request
public_ip_open = urllib.request.urlopen("https://ident.me").read().decode("utf8")
print(public_ip_open)
```